# Adding a new partition Kafka 0.8.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

For a particular topic we want to have one partition per broker. The idea is that to scale we keep on adding brokers. However, when I test out how new partitions are added it does not work in the way I would expect. For example, I have three brokers: 2064029428, 2064029280, 2064028458. I create a new topic:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zk.net:2181/stream --topic test --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk.net:2181/stream --topic test
Topic:test  PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 2064029428  Replicas: 2064029428    Isr: 2064029428
Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 2064028458  Replicas: 2064028458    Isr: 2064028458
```

I then alter the topic to add another partition.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper zk.net:2181/stream --topic test --partitions 3

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk.net:2181/stream --topic test
Topic:test  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 2064029428  Replicas: 2064029428    Isr: 2064029428
Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 2064028458  Replicas: 2064028458    Isr: 2064028458
Topic: test Partition: 2    Leader: 2064029428  Replicas: 2064029428    Isr: 2064029428
```

I would have expected the new partition to have been created on broker 2064029280 since it does not currently have a partition. Instead I get two partitions on the same broker 2064029428. Is this expected? Is there a way to control where the new partition is added? I tried the `--replica-assignment` option, which works when creating the topic, but doesn't not work when altering the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in kafka doc, currently you have to manually trigger reassignment.

> In 0.8.1, the partition reassignment tool does not have the capability to automatically study the data distribution in a Kafka cluster and move partitions around to attain an even load distribution. As such, the admin has to figure out which topics or partitions should be moved around.

In short you have to use `bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool with the manually crafted migration plan.

See [guide on manual reassignment](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_cluster_expansion) for more.

Answer (score 0):

To add more to the answer above and more clarification, since the broker 2064029280 does not have any partition, it would have been added to the cluster after the partitions for the topic was created. Else, partitions would be distributed evenly across brokers in the cluster by default and broker 2064029280 would also have had the partition. 
When we alter the partitions, after new broker(2064029280) is added. the new partitions will get evenly distributed across all, rather than just the new broker since "the partition reassignment tool does not have the capability to automatically study the data distribution in a Kafka cluster". Hence, it does not just assign (all) new partitions to the new broker to balance data distribution.